# Excel VBA - How to copy multiple ranges given conditions to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, copy-paste

I'm very new to VBA. I have a sheet that has multiple ranges I'd like to copy and paste into an existing spreadsheet based on certain conditions. I tried working off a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572110/excel-vba-how-to-copy-multiple-ranges-from-same-sheet), but am still having difficulties. I'd like each copied range to paste below the last row with a 1-row space between them.

For the purpose of this thread, let's say sourceSheet is the name of the sheet with all the data, and targetSheet is the sheet I am trying to plot to

For the first function, I'd like to search two cells, "A67" for a name and "B117" for a number. These two parameters (number and name) are associated with a range of cell to be copied (A68:K125). Each name, number, and range is offset by 11 columns (first name is in A67, next one is in L67). There are 50 set of ranges all offset by 11 columns, but I'd like to make it so that if additional ranges are added, the program can evaluate them as well.

I am trying to identify the max number associated with the given name, and plot its associated range based off of that.

Ex. [Bob,15] [John,16] [John,22] [Bob,35] [Bob,12]

copy and paste range associated with [Bob,35] and range associated with [John,22]

---

The second function would look at a number only and copy the associated range. I'd like to search cell, "G195" to see if it is "NOT" 0. If it is any number but zero, it would plot the associated range (A162:K191). Each number and range is offset by 11 columns (first number is in G195, next one is in R195). There are 50 set of ranges all offset by 11 columns, but I'd like to make it so that if additional ranges are added, the program can evaluate them as well.

I had it working on a simpler function, but for whatever reason, the format wasn't kept. I'd like to carry over the format (font,size, bold, colored cell) but it was not working. Also, I have some images that are within these range cells that is not being copied over.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. I posted the code I wrote for the second function. I have no idea how to write the first function.

```
Sub Copy_Electrical_Calcs()

'
' Copy_Electrical_Calcs Macro
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim variableRange As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim fileName As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim variable As String

Set targetSheet = Worksheets("targetSheet")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sourceSheet")
    Set rngToCopy = .Range("A162:K191")
    Set variableRange = .Range("G195")
End With
For i = 1 To 4
    if(variableRange <> 0)
    lastrow = Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("targetSheet").Range(lastrow + 1).Resize(rngToCopy.Rows.count, rngToCopy.Columns.count).Value = rngToCopy.Value
    variableRange.ClearContents

    ' Increment our ranges:
    Set variableRange = variableRange.Offset(0, 11)
    Set rngToCopy = rngToCopy.Offset(0, 11)
Next
ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you need, if you do not show us what you have against what you want to accomplish... Too many words to be processed and people does not have enough patience and time to invest in your problem. How "are associated with a range of cell to be copied (A68:K125)"? What does this mean?

Comment: What does "range associated with [Bob,35]" mean?

Comment: Do you ask a question only for the sake of asking?

Comment: @FaneDuru, Thank you for your feedback. This is my first post, so I apologize if this is somewhat difficult to understand. I know the post is long, but I tried to provide as much information as possible so that the reader could understand my intention. Sounds like I was not successful in this attempt.

Comment: I have multiple ranges of cells that I want to copy and paste into another sheet based on certain conditions. A68:K125 is one of those ranges. offset by 11 columns is another set of L68:V125 is another range that I'd like to copy and paste, and so on.

Comment: I am not just asking for the sake of asking. I am trying to create an electrical calculations package. each range is a set of calculations for a piece of given equipment. "bob" is the name of the equipment, and "35" is its maximum current. I want to copy the range of calculations for the highest current of that equipment. "Bob" "15", is the same piece of equipment analyzed with a lower current value, with a different range of calculations associated with it. I only want to copy over the range of calcs for the highest current of that specific equipment. Hope that clarifies things.